# GNU GCC bug when using both sysroot and c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, arm, yocto

I'm encountering a very strange issue. I've used Yocto Project to generate me an ARM toolchain/RFS. This in itself may not important since I've since replicated the same issue with a pre-made ARM toolchain and empty sysroot (see edit below)

Consider the simple file `foo.cpp`:

```
#include <memory>
int main() { return 0; }
```

I am able to compile it with either `--sysroot=...` *or* `-std=c++11` flags, but never both.

For example, the following compiles fine:

`aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ --sysroot=/opt/sysroots/my_sysroot foo.cpp`

This also compiles fine:

`aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ -std=c++11 foo.cpp`

However, this does not work:

`aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ --sysroot=/opt/sysroots/my_sysroot -std=c++11 foo.cpp`

The compiler error I get is:

```
In file included from foo.cpp:2:0:
/opt/marvell/5.2.1/armv8/le/aarch64v8-marvell-linux-gnu-5.2.1_x86_64_20151110/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/c++/5.2.1/memory: In function 'void* std::align(std::size_t, std::size_t, void*&, std::size_t&)':
/opt/marvell/5.2.1/armv8/le/aarch64v8-marvell-linux-gnu-5.2.1_x86_64_20151110/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/c++/5.2.1/memory:117:58: error: cast from 'void*' to 'uintptr_t {aka unsigned int}' loses precision [-fpermissive]
   const auto __intptr = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(__ptr);
```

Compiler information:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=aarch64-linux-gnu-g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/marvell/5.2.1/armv8/le/aarch64v8-marvell-linux-gnu-5.2.1_x86_64_20151110/bin/../libexec/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5.2.1/lto-wrapper
Target: aarch64-linux-gnu
Configured with: /home/gccbuilder-x86/release/mgcc5.0/src/gcc-src/configure --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=aarch64-linux-gnu --prefix=/home/gccbuilder-x86/release/mgcc5.0/Release/install/aarch64v8-marvell-linux-gnu-5.2.1_x86_64 --enable-libssp --enable-shared --enable-threads --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-pkgversion='Marvell GCC release 20151110-a53c013d' --with-bugurl=mailto:mrvlgccbug@gmail.com --with-sysroot=/home/gccbuilder-x86/release/mgcc5.0/Release/install/aarch64v8-marvell-linux-gnu-5.2.1_x86_64/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc --with-build-sysroot=/home/gccbuilder-x86/release/mgcc5.0/Release/install/aarch64v8-marvell-linux-gnu-5.2.1_x86_64/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' --with-build-time-tools=/home/gccbuilder-x86/release/mgcc5.0/Release/install/aarch64v8-marvell-linux-gnu-5.2.1_x86_64/aarch64-linux-gnu/bin --enable-poison-system-directories --enable-symvers=gnu --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-multiarch --enable-linker-build-id --disable-nls --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libcc1 --with-specs='%{funwind-tables|fno-unwind-tables|ffreestanding|nostdlib:;:-funwind-tables}' --disable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.2.1 20151103 (Marvell GCC release 20151110-a53c013d)
```

Any insights on how to go about debugging this? I want to determine which party is responsible (GCC, Yocto, Marvell, etc) before attempting to file a bug report.

Edit:

I found an easy way to reproduce this. Simply download [Linaro's](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest/aarch64-linux-gnu/) x86_64 compiler and invoke with an empty sysroot:

`./aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ --sysroot="" -std=c++11 foo.cpp`

Comment: What are `sizeof(uintptr_t)` and `sizeof(void*)` when you compile with and without sysroot?

Comment: @n.m. with sysroot: `4 8` respectively, without sysroot (but with c++11): `8 8` respectively, and with neither sysroot nor c++11 `8 8` respectively. That's a very good clue! Do you know what could cause this?

Comment: It looks like a bug in your particular gcc build to me. Try `g++ -dM -E - < /dev/null | grep __UINTPTR_TYPE__` with and without sysroot. I get the same results with my gcc, do you get different results?

Comment: How do you get the sysroot? I have tested both with the ubuntu cross compiler and Yocto SDK, both work indicating sysroot generated by Yocto sdk. Only other difference is I use gcc 5.4, I don't think it's the problem tho

Comment: @n.m. I get the same result in both cases: `#define __UINTPTR_TYPE__ long unsigned int` and if I print `sizeof(long unsigned int)` with and without sysroot I get `8` both times. However, if I print `sizeof(uintptr_t)` with and without sysroot I get `4` and `8` respectively.

Comment: @DavidBensoussan I just ran `bitbake meta-toolchain` to generate the toolchain and RFS installer

Comment: @DavidBensoussan I'm was suspecting the RFS generated by Yocto as well, however I can reproduce the issue using Linaro's premade toolchain and an empty sysroot. If I print `sizeof(uintptr_t)` with `--sysroot=""` then it prints `4`, otherwise if I compile without sysroot it prints `8`

Comment: This is very interesting, something causes uintptr_t to be defined to something else than `__UINTPTR_TYPE__` which is not normal. Try running `strace -e open -f g++ ...` for the two cases and see if the compiler opens different sets of files in each case.

Comment: @n.m. Ah, thanks, using `strace` I found the compiler is opening a different `wordsize.h` depending on if using sysroot or not. In the case of sysroot, it's using `wordsize.h` in the RFS itself and contains `#define __WORDSIZE 32`, in the case of no sysroot it's using `wordsize.h` in the toolchain and contains `#define __WORDSIZE 64`. Could this be the issue? If so, it could indicate I have some kind of Yocto config issue.

Comment: Yes this might indeed be the problem.

Comment: If you pass an empty sysroot, it's as if you passed `/`, I suppose?